# bidirectional signal not assinging HiZ in a nested assignment

Tags: verilog

While assigning HiZ and 1'b0 signals to a bidirectional port using a nested assignment, I always get 1'b0 in output.

I am trying to create a bidirectional port for my design

```
assign sig_bidir = (state==state1 || state==state2|| state==state3)? (sig1? 1'b0: 1'bZ): 1'bZ;
```

When the state match happens, sig_bidir is stuck at 1'b0. It should appropriately follow 1'b0 or HiZ depending on the state of sig1.

Comment: Please show declarations for all signals and their current values.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer during my debug. It is not related to the statement above. The above statement is correct.